# How to config CSF to allow postrouting in iptables for installing OpenVPN?

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, csf, lfd

I am installing OpenVPN on my server and according to the tutorial I'm following I have to add the following line to iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I add it and save it and successfully restart iptables but then I have noticed that when I use CSF, it overrides iptables and this line get erased. How can I prevent CSF+LFD from erasing this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is possible by adding a bash file named csfpre.sh in /etc/csf/ directory with the iptables rules that you want CSF to load each time it starts.

On CentOS, I had to write /sbin/iptables instead of iptables alone because writing iptables alone gave the "command not found" error in bash. In other words, you should write

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

in csfpre.sh for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working steps you may follow to work with CSF+OpenVPN droplet.

ref: https://vvcares.com/blog/post/openvpn-csf-configuration

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OPENVPN WITH CSF CONFIGURATION
There is a working steps you may follow to work with CSF+OpenVPN droplet.
ref: https://vvcares.com/blog/post/openvpn-csf-configuration

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/502747)